# Creating React App, Aborting installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I just started encountering this error.
It been working before running:

```
create-react-app and 
npx create-react-app
```

All of a suden, it started giving me this error on anything I run:

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.21.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/react: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\REACT JS PROJECT\my-app\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\REACT JS PROJECT\my-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Done.

What could be the error, I have cleared cache like five times

Comment: PEM routines would suggest a certificate problem (SSL), transient error perhaps?

Comment: Try yarn config set strict-ssl false

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running:

del -rf node_modules package-lock.json and npm cache clean --force
on windows.